# How to play Flash videos with a Gecko WebBrowser? (GeckoFX)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, gecko

I'm using the GeckoFX 'GeckoWebBrowser' user control to navigate but I can't play Flash videos of any page, for example if I try to navigate to youtube it always displays this error:

[image]

There is a way to enable Flash videos?

> UPDATE:

I've set this property:

```
GeckoPreferences.Default("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False
```

...And now the background of the videos are shown but I can't reproduce any video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the "Emoticon" who says that this video is unaivailbe : this is because the page is not showing properly so you can see all `divisions` what should be `hidden` in the page like  `you must enable JavaScript in your browser.`

i had simmilar problems with `GeckoFx` my suggestion is moving to `WEBKITDOTNET` is the best for now as compenent

[Here](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/)